# What happened to Flag Weight?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, flags

Up to a couple of days ago, I could go into my account and see me flag weight, but now it just seems to show how many helpful flags I've raised. It seems the badges related, Deputy and Marshal, have changed as well.

So what happened in the last couple of days?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See here please: [What happened to flag weight?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119715/what-happened-to-flag-weight).

Accepted answer copied for convenience

---

It is dead.

[We don't need (to see) flag weight!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84859/we-dont-need-to-see-flag-weight)

From Waffles @ https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119714/143601:

> We now only show the number of helpful flags on your profile page (visible only to you) ... this number only ever increases.
>
> Flag weight on the other hand, is gone ... it is dead.

It seems that [Deputy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/140/deputy) has also been changed to **80 helpful flags** along with the change to [Marshal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/160/marshal) at ***500*** (holy crap!)

Comment: Wow, I got Deputy in the nick of time, I reached the required flag weight on Thursday...

Comment: This is great. Now I only have to strangle *one* kitten in frustration when I get a flag declined. Also gold badge, woot